# How can I formulate this 'if-then' constraint problem?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint-programming, logical-constraints

I have five integer variables, and I need to write some constraints on them:

$x_0$ , $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ]$.  $1 \leq x_i \leq 3$

- if $x_0 =1$  then no constraint on  $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ]$
- if $x_0 =2$  then  1 $\in$ $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ]$
- if $x_0 =3$  then  1,2 $\in$ $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ]$

What is the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Final model here ?  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/happy-neighbors-guaranteed-pyomo-alireza-soroudi/?trackingId=la50d4fkTR%2BatGprKRYFeQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option: first define $x_i$ with binaries:

\begin{align}
x_i&=y_i^1+2y_i^2+3y_i^3 \\
1&=y_i^1+y_i^2+y_i^3 \\
y_i^j &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

You can enforce $x_0=2 \implies 1 \in [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ with:
$$
y_0^2 \implies \bigvee_{i=1}^4 y_i^1 \quad  \equiv \quad  y_0^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^1 
$$

And $x_0=3 \implies 1,2 \in [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] $ with $
y_0^3 \implies (\bigvee_{i=1}^4 y_i^1) \wedge (\bigvee_{i=1}^4 y_i^2)$:

$$ y_0^3 \le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^1  \\
y_0^3 \le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^2 
$$

Comment: Your $\ge 1-(2-x_0)$ is too restrictive when $x_0=3$.

Comment: Yes, thank you !! safer to work with binaries all the way.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a binary-expansion-based modification of @Kuifje’s formulation, and it uses fewer variables and constraints, but the last two are quadratic:

\begin{align}
x_i&=y_i^1+2y_i^2 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$}\\
1&\le y_i^1+y_i^2 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$}\\
y_i^j &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$ and $j\in\{1,2\}$}\\
y_0^2 &\le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^1 (1-y_i^2) \\
y_0^1 + y_0^2 -1&\le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^2 (1-y_i^1)
\end{align}

There are $196$ feasible solutions.

[PORTA](https://porta.zib.de/) yields the following (linear) formulation with $10$ variables and $21$ constraints for the $y$ space:
\begin{align}
y_i^1 + y_i^2 &\ge 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$} \\
y_i^j &\le 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$ and $j\in\{1,2\}$} \\
\sum_{i=0}^4 y_i^2 &\le 4 \\
y_0^1 + y_0^2 + \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^1 &\le 5 \\
\sum_{i=0}^4 \sum_{j=1}^2 y_i^j &\le 7 + y_k^1 + y_k^2 && \text{for $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$} \\
\end{align}

---

For comparison, note that PORTA yields the following formulation with $15$ variables and $26$ constraints for @Kuifje's $y_i^j$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^3 y_i^j &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$}\\
y_i^j &\ge 0 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,4\}$ and $j\in\{1,2,3\}$} \\
y_0^3 &\le \sum_{i=1}^4 y_i^2 \\
\sum_{i=0}^4 y_i^3 &\le 3 + y_k^3 &&\text{for $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$}\\
\sum_{i=0}^4 (y_i^2+y_i^3) &\le 4
\end{align}

Comment: I finally did this. 
$\forall_{n} \sum_{j\in A_0} y_{j,n} \geq \sum_{m>n} y_{0,m} $ 
Where 
$A_0 = [x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4]$

Comment: @Optimizationteam Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score -1):

As @RobPratt implies an integer can be expressed as $2^{n}y^{n}$ with $ n =\{0,1,2,...\}$ & $y$ as binary.
So integers $[x_i] $ can be expressed as $2^ny_i^{n} $ where $n =\{0,1\}$
Constraints can be
$ x_0 - 1 \le 2\sum_{i=1}^4 y_{i}^0$
$x_0-2 \le \sum_i y_{i}^1 \le 5-x_0$

Comment: Right idea, but needs correction when  $x_0=3$.

Comment: @RobPratt Completed the answer just now

Comment: Sorry, still not right.

Comment: @RobPratt yes an upper bound was needed.

Comment: Your $x_0-1\le$ constraint is too restrictive when $x_0=3$.

Comment: @RobPratt now it takes care of it

Comment: This yields only 178 solutions when there should be 196.